# Call custom Event once (Game Development)

Tags: java, custom-events

So i am writing a rpg java game and decided to use custom events to make the communication between two classes easier. At first i wrote an "enemyDeathEvent" to let the player know if an enemy died.

First i made my EnemyListener:

```
public interface EnemyListener {

    public void playerDeathEvent(EnemyEvent e);
}
```

After that i created the EnemyEvent class:

```
public class EnemyEvent {

    private Enemy enemy;

    public EnemyEvent(Enemy enemy) {
        this.enemy = enemy;
    }

    public Enemy getSource() {
        return enemy;
    }
}
```

Then i set up the Enemy class:

```
public class Enemy {

    //......
    private boolean dead;

    private Set<EnemyListener> listeners;

    public Enemy() {
        listeners = new HashSet<EnemyListener>();
    }

    //checks if the enemy is dead
    public void update() {
        if(health <= 0) dead = true;

        if(dead) fireDeathEvent();
    }

    //fires the death event
    protecd synchronized void fireDeathEvent() {
        EnemyEvent e = new EnemyEvent(this);
        for(EnemyListener listener : listeners) {
            listeners.enemyDeathEvent(e);
        }
    }

    public void addEnemyListener(EnemyListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }  
}
```

Lastly, in implemented the EnemyListener to the player:

```
public class Player implements EnemyListener {

    @Override
    public void enemyDeathEvent(EnemyEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getSource().getName() + " died!");
    }
}
```

So when the enemy dies the **enemyDeathEvent()** method from my player class will be called. everything works fine **but my actual problem is that the game call this method more than once**. the reason is that my **update()** method is connected to a thread which updates the game physics etc 30 times per second.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while(gameRunning) {
        update();
        render();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000/30);  //30FPS
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is: How can i solve this problem so that my method will be called once?

I would appreciate every help! thanks

Comment: You seem to have an event driven program. Why do you have a multiple threads? I would recommend you to have a single thread (a timer) that updates the game 30 times per second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop updating your `Enemy` instance once it is dead.

Something like:

```
void update() {
    if (dead) return;
    ...
}
```

As a more general purpose solution, all your game instances should inherit from a base class (e.g. `EntityBase`). The base class can have a field named `isEnabled` and a basic update method:

```
void update() {
    if (!isEnabled) return;
    updateImpl();
}
abstract void updateImpl();
```

All classes inheriting your `EntityBase` class must implements the `updateImpl()` method. Now to stop updating an instance, you just need to set the `isEnabled` flag to `false`.

```
void updateImpl() {
    if(health <= 0) {
        dead = true;
        isEnabled = false;
    }
    if(dead) fireDeathEvent();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could update the `dead` field and fire the event only once, when the enemy dies:

```
public void update() {
    if(!dead && health <= 0) {
        dead = true;
        fireDeathEvent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Or a Boolean class variable that indicates if it has fired the event yet?

Answer (score 0):

You need some special state for enemy that indicates killed state and check it in update method